# AJAX call to .asmx - fails when function is defined

Tags: jquery, asp.net, ajax

I trigger AJAX call when button is pressed. When I use `error: function (response) {...}` it works but when I try to use function I have defined before like
`error: AjaxCallFailed(response)` it does not.

Is it possible to define my own functions or I have to use anonymous function ? It is quite important for my script clarity.

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {

    function AjaxCallFailed(r) {
    alert('failed:' + r.status + ':' + r.responseText);
    };

        $("#btnPickADate").click(function () { CallForTemplate(2); });

        function CallForTemplate(tid) {
            $.ajax({
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                type: "POST",
                url: "../WebService/MyService.asmx/GetTemplates",
                data: JSON.stringify({ 'myId': tid }),
                dataType: "json",
                success: function (response) {
                      ...
                    }
                },
                //error: AjaxCallFailed(response) <-- This does not work.
                error: function (response) {
                    alert('failed:' + response.status + ':' + response.responseText);
                }
            });
        };

    });
</script>
```

Error in browser console

> ReferenceError: response is not defined
>
> CallForTemplate
>
> jQuery.Callbacks/fire
>
> jQuery.Callbacks/self.fireWith
>
> .ready
>
> completed

Comment: You need to create an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that shows your code in better context (show the AJAX call taking place and how that's wired up to your function).